# hyperlink in label

Tags: manipulate

In a `FrameLabel` for `Manipulate`, I would like part of the string to be a hyperlink. Is this possible? I have tried various things (e.g. insert hyperlink, and the Hyperlink function) but nothing has worked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
 Manipulate[u, {u, 0, 1}, 
 FrameLabel -> {Hyperlink["Wolfram Research, Inc.", "http://www.wolfram.com"], 
  Hyperlink["FrameLabel", "paclet:ref/FrameLabel"], 
  Column[{Hyperlink[Style["this Q/A", "Section", 24], 
      "http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16224/125"], 
  Hyperlink["Hyperlink", "paclet:ref/Hyperlink"]}], 
  Hyperlink["Manipulate", "paclet:ref/Manipulate"]}, 
  RotateLabel -> True]
```

[image]

For lables that contain hyperlinks interspersed with strings:

```
 Manipulate[u, {u, 0, 1},  FrameLabel -> 
 Row[{"Please see the doc pages \n ", 
    Hyperlink["FrameLabel",    
    "http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FrameLabel.html"], 
     " and ", Hyperlink["Hyperlink", "paclet:ref/Hyperlink"]}]]
```

[image]